# security algorithms using prime numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, proof-writing

many security algorithms makes two primes, say $x$ and $y$ and multiplying them. The security is derived from the fact that it's difficult to factor it back into $x$ and $y$.

But, cannot we (programs) makes use of the fact that the primes must be of the form $6k \pm 1$ and generate large primes and find out factors?  I know it is not that easy still as otherwise many security algorithms may compromise. But, why is it still difficult or do we have an easy way to generate large primes and such factors programmatically using any of the straight mathematical principles of numbers and combinatorics?

Comment: why is it difficult? cannot we use pre-generated primes and try to crack? division in loop using per-generated primes must not be difficult for a computer?

Comment: Even noting that all primes (except $2$ and $3$) are of the form $6k\pm 1$ still only reduces the number of possible prime factors to check by a factor of $3$. There are more sophisticated factorization algorithms that are way better than this, but their run time nevertheless grows incredibly rapidly as the number of digits increases.

Anyway, you can get a feel for how difficult this is by trying to write a program that factorizes large numbers, and see how long it takes for numbers with a couple hundred digits.

Comment: @Moo, sure, will see as per the details obtained in the comments.

Comment: @Moo non-existent as far as we, the public, know...

Comment: @Moo, you mean to say, there are lot of research happening worldwide in this connection of breaking RSA and still no one succeeded?

Comment: @Moo, for a beginner, do you have any suggestion of a book or website to start with?

Comment: @Moo you deleted the link? why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prime numbers chosen for a lot of these security algorithms are insanely large and it would take a computer far too much time to check all possibilities (after all, there are infinitely many primes). I believe a common estimate is longer than the age of our universe. Such large primes can be chosen as multiplying them together is trivial compared to factorising.

However, you may want to look into quantum computing and especially [Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor's_algorithm).

Comment: It seems to me that if we have a list of the first $k$ primes, then RSA randomly selects two and gives the product $pq$.  So it would take $O(k^2)$ time to brute-force factor.  Intuitively, this does not seem much larger than the complexity required to generate the first $k$ primes in the first place (back-of-the-envelope:  Each prime $p$ takes $\sqrt{p}$ to check, and if there are $k$ primes then checking all of them takes $\approx k^{1.5}$ complexity.)  So it seems there is only a difference between $k^{1.5}$ and $k^2$.  Is this correct?

Comment: But in practice RSA uses pseudo-primes instead of choosing from a list.

Comment: There are prime-verifying algorithms whose run time would be about $\log(p)$ (that is, they are polynomial time with respect to the number of digits of $p$).

Comment: Thanks Fabio.  So, it still seems non-obvious what the complexity advantages are, though it is used in practice so it must be "hard" to crack.

Comment: @Michael The problem with having a list and using the brute-force factor is that you would have to store this list - a list which could be very very large.

Comment: @florence : Is your $\log(p)$ fact correct?  Wikipedia suggests that such performance is only available via quantum computers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Comment: @Michael The AKS algorithm runs in polynomial time.

Comment: @florence : Thanks.  The wiki page I looked at made no mention. So I suppose the advantage in quantum computing is only to reduce the exponent on the $\log(p)$.

Comment: You have to distinguish primality testing from factorization.  The latter is supposed to be harder.

Comment: @florence : Your $\log(p)$ observation helps me understand the security gains of RSA the most, yet it is funny that the result seems developed years _after_ RSA.  So I suppose the other reasons mentioned above were significant.

Comment: There's no chronology problem, because practical implementations of RSA don't run AKS, but generate random numbers with usually 512 or 1024 bits and then use something like Rabin and Miller's primality test to guarantee that a number is prime with very high probability.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi, so there is no proof to show that Rabin and Miller's primality test  generates a prime ?

Comment: @Kiran The Rabin-Miller test is a probabilistic test.  You give it a number and it tells you either that it's composite, in which case it's guaranteed that the number is composite, or that it may be prime.  If a number passes multiple runs of the test, the probability that it's prime is high.  AKS is a remarkable algorithm, but it's very slow in practice for the kind of numbers that are interesting in practice.

Answer (score 2):

A similar question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267632/rainbow-tables-as-a-solution-to-large-prime-factoring

You are describing trying to factor large (300+ digit) semi-primes using trial division.  This is incredibly inefficient.

Let us use an example.  We have a 1024-bit properly constructed RSA key.  This is smaller than is recommended, but it will work for us.  Assume that the factors are about the same size -- each 512 bits.  How many 512-bit primes are there?  There are approximately

18906370642694531692280566048023127923485724683677704823332410535612010986516861319713332210777885374982269703605238438348574735930806171464068948672356

512-bit primes.  Wagstaff (2015) uses a simpler estimate of $18.85 \times 10^{150}$.  Forget AKS and so on -- assume that we have all the primes we need for free, and of course we're skipping all the composites that 6k +/-1 will let through.  Let's start doing trial division!

Pretend that each 1024-bit modulo takes 1 nanosecond.  Further assume that you have a trillion trillion computers all churning away at this, every power station on earth routed to this, etc.  The sun will exhaust its fuel before you've even made any sort of noticeable dent in the number of primes you have to check.

The issue isn't really the speed of generating or detecting primes, or the speed of checking a factor.  It's that humans have a hard time understanding how truly big these numbers are.

Additional notes:

- the estimate has many gratuitous digits.  Using proven bounds, the number would be between $18.90637019 \times 10^{150}$ and $18.90637108 \times 10^{150}$.  If the Riemann Hypothesis is true, then the number given has 73 correct digits.  It's not really relevant to the question, but a fun digression.
- I'm not going to do any probability work, but we do note there are 2 primes in the range we're looking for, and on average we wouldn't have to search the whole range.  This reduces our work by a factor of 4 or so which doesn't change our final thoughts at this size.
- The cost for `mpz_divisible_p(n,d)` with a 1024-bit semiprime `n` and 512-bit `d` seems to be about 80 nanoseconds.  That's faster than I thought it would be, though my example still used only 1 ns.
- To actually generate primes in this range, we'd use a partial sieve followed by primality tests for the candidates.  In this application we'd skip the latter.  The OP discusses a sieve to depth 3, but we can certainly sieve deeper for little cost, either with a larger wheel or an actual sieve.  Using Perl/ntheory, with a starting point of $2^{511}+2^{510}$ it takes 8 seconds on a single core to sieve a range of $10^{10}$ to depth 7 and make a list of the 2,285,714,286 candidates.  Sieving to depth 1000 takes 18 seconds for 809,654,165 candidates -- probably a good tradeoff.  Depth 100,000 takes 35 seconds for 487,523,044 candidates.  Depth 1,000,000,000 takes 66 seconds and yields 270,928,603 candidates.  Note that $10^{10}$ is a pathetically small portion of the range we're searching.